# How to build double dispatch using extensions

Tags: c#, double-dispatch

I have a library that have a hierarchy of class as follow:

```
class Base {}
class A : Base {}
class B : Base {}
```

Now I wanted to do different thing depending on type of my object whether it is an A or a B.
So I decide to go for and implement double dispatching to avoid checking type.

```
class ClientOfLibrary {

    public DoStuff(Base anObject)
    {
       anObject.MakeMeDoStuff(this);
    }

    private void DoStuffForanA(A anA);
    private void DoStuffForaB(B aB);
}
```

Now the canonical way of implementing double dispatch is to make the method `MakeMeDoStuff` abstract in `Base` and overload it in concrete class. But remember that `Base`, `A` and `B` are in library so I can not go and add does method freely.

Adding method extension wont work because there is no way to add an abstract extensions.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Except copying Base, A, B code in your own MyBase , MyA extends MyBase , MyB extends MyBase I don't really see an alternative. I remember we had to do something like this when I was working with c#

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `dynamic` calls:

```
class ClientOfLibrary {

    public DoStuff(Base o)
    {
       DoStuffInternal((dynamic)o);
    }

    private void DoStuffInternal(A anA) { }
    private void DoStuffInternal(B aB) { }
    private void DoStuffInternal(Base o) { /* unsupported type */ }
}
```

C# natively supports multiple dispatch since introduction of `dynamic`, so implementing visitor pattern is unnecessary in most cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, this also significantly simplifies the [Selective Visitor Pattern](http://www.educery.com/papers/patterns/visitors/selective.visitor.html)!