# Polymorphic uncurried method calls (adhoc polymorphism) in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading, double-dispatch, adhoc-polymorphism

Let me start with an example.

Say I have an abstract `Vehicle` class.

```
public abstract class Vehicle {

    public Vehicle() {}

    public abstract void ride();

}
```

And classes `Car` and `Bicycle` that inherit from this abstract class.

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {

    public Car() {}

    @Override
    public void ride() {
        System.out.println("Riding the car.");
    }

}

public class Bicycle extends Vehicle {

    public Bicycle() {}

    @Override
    public void ride() {
        System.out.println("Riding the bicycle.");
    }

}
```

When I apply the `ride()` method to an object of type `Vehicle` whose actual type can only be determined at runtime, the JVM will apply the correct version of `ride()`.

That is, in a curried method call of the sort `v.ride()`, polymorphism works the expected way.

But what if I have an external implementation in form of a method that only accepts a subtype of `Vehicle` as an argument? So, what if I have `repair(Bicycle b)` and `repair(Car c)` methods? The uncurried polymorphic method call `repair(v)` won't work.

Example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

private static void playWithVehicle() {
    List<Vehicle> garage = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    garage.add(new Car());
    garage.add(new Car());
    garage.add(new Bicycle());
    garage.forEach((v) -> v.ride()); // Works.
    garage.forEach((v) -> {
        /* This would be nice to have.
        repair(v.castToRuntimeType());
        */

        // This is an ugly solution, but the obvious way I can think of.
        switch (v.getClass().getName()) {
        case "Bicycle":
            repair((Bicycle) v);
            break;
        case "Car":
            repair((Car) v);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    });
}

private static void repair(Bicycle b) {
    System.out.println("Repairing the bicycle.");
}

private static void repair(Car c) {
    System.out.println("Repairing the car.");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    playWithVehicle();
}

}
```

I have to check for the class name and downcast. Is there a better solution to this?

---

**Edit:** My actual purpose is that I'm traversing an abstract syntax tree and I happened to notice that I want double dispatch.

`Ast` is an abstract class from which actual AST nodes like `Assign`, `MethodCall`, or `ReturnStmt` inherit. `body` is a polymorphic list of `Ast`s.

Code snippet:

```
List<Ast> body;

body.parallelStream().forEach((ast) -> {
    // This one won't work.
    visit(ast);
    // This one will work.
    if (ast instanceof Assign) {
        visit((Assign) ast);
    } else if (ast instance of MethodCall) {
        visit((MethodCall) ast);
    } else if (ast instance of ReturnStmt) {
        visit((ReturnStmt) ast);
    }
    // etc. for other AST nodes
});

private void visit(Assign ast) {

}

private void visit(MethodCall ast) {

}

private void visit(ReturnStmt ast) {

}
```

My only possibilities of achieving double dispatch is either checking the class and downcasting or properly implementing the visitor pattern, right?

Comment: In any case, don't switch on the class name. What if you have a `MountainBicycle` which is a subclass of `Bicycle`?

Comment: You're right! I didn't think of this. Well then, this would become a lot of `if` and `else if` statements of the form `if(Bicycle.class.isAssignableFrom(v.getClass()))`.

Comment: You mean `if v instanceof Bicycle`...

Comment: Ah, of course! I initially thought subclasses would not be part of `instanceof`.

Comment: Anyway, regarding your actual question, I doubt you'll be able to get a good expert answer, because usually solutions for such situations depend on the actual, practical use case, not "toy classes" like `Vehicle`,`Car`,`Bicycle`, or toy methods that do nothing but print. If you post a real-world problem it would be easier to answer (though even then it could just end up as "opinion-based").

Comment: (1) What's your actual purpose for doing this? (2) Maybe you should just use Groovy in dynamic mode.

Comment: I don't think *curried* and *uncurried* are appropriate terms, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**: There is no multiple dispatch in Java and it can be simulated by `instanceof` or by the visitor pattern.

See here: 
[Java method overloading + double dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794195/java-method-overloading-double-dispatch)

See also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#Examples_of_emulating_multiple_dispatch

On a sidenote, exactly this is possible in C# with `dynamic` calls: [How to build double dispatch using extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912603/how-to-build-double-dispatch-using-extensions)

And this is also possible in the many languages that are compiled to JVM bytecode, e.g. Groovy was mentioned.